# Twilio Whatsapp Sandbox Configuration for deploying application via AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, twilio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl5RP.png)

Currently I am developing a chatbot for my application with django, using a twilio trial account.
The chatbot functions properly with ngrok.io, i.e. when the server is operating locally, which mean that when I send a whatsapp message to the twilio sandbox with operation of simply "python manage.py runserver", he will automatically reply me according to my script.

However, as I started deploying the application using the AWS elastic beanstalk, I found that it is only possible for the sandbox to send out whatsapp message by POST request on the web application, but not capable to respond to POST request sent out from whatsapp.

In what way I can deal with it? Is it related to AWS settings or Twilio settings? Some CORS related issues?

Great thanks in advance.

(Please forgive me if my use of language is not accurate as I am not with computer science background.)

Below is part of the code that I applied.

```
@csrf_exempt
def message(request):

    account_sid = 'xxx' 
    auth_token = 'xxx' 
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token) 

    client_phone_number = request.POST.get('From').removeprefix("whatsapp:+852")
    client_phone_number.removeprefix("+852")
    incoming_message = request.POST.get('Body')
    conversation_sid = request.POST.get('conversation_sid')


    incoming_message = incoming_message.lower()
    response = MessagingResponse()


#processing the incoming message to produce the text

    resp = "text"


    response.message(resp)

    return HttpResponse(str(response))
```

I have tried pasting https://xxxxx-env.yyyyyyy.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/whatsapp/ to the sandbox configuration cell as shown in the image and it resulted to what I mentioned above. The whatsapp url is set just like typically done for other urls for django, followed by message(request) to process the request sent out from the whatsapp. Any other proper way I can do it?

Comment: Do you see your message and potential errors in the [message and error logs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/debugging-tools), respectively?

Comment: @IObert 
[2022-12-20 18:17:48 +0000] [3256] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2022-12-21 02:17:48 +0800] [3344] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3344)
<WSGIRequest: GET '/whatsapp/'>
[2022-12-20 18:17:49 +0000] [3256] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2022-12-20 18:17:49 +0000] [3883] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-12-20 18:17:49 +0000] [3883] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (3883)
[2022-12-20 18:17:49 +0000] [3883] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2022-12-20 18:17:49 +0000] [3967] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3967
This is what I have got. Hope to see if problem can be identified

Comment: It seems that this is your application log but I was referring to the log in the Twilio console.